# How to pass "this" from element to function

Tags: jquery

Would like to DRY some link functions. Very basic example:

```
<p><a href="" data-href="Foo" class="link">Bar</a></p>

function Link() {
    var link = $(this).attr("data-href");
    alert(link);
}

$('.link').on('click',function(e){
    Link(this)
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The alert dialog returns 'undefined' instead of the data-href value. How can I pass the value from the click handler to the function? Ive looked at several examples, and nothing seems to get the desired effect. Using variations of ($(this)) doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Why would it need to be `this`? Seems you know about passing parameters to a function (like `e` in the click callback).

Comment: I want to reference a data attribute like I would $(this).attr('data-href'); Good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO just add parameter to function Link:

```js
function Link(link) {
  var link = $(link).attr("data-href");
  alert(link);
}

$('.link').on('click',function(e){
  Link(this)
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You are welcome! Please submit this answer... Thanks